# Python how to check if a file is opened using notepad

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system

My code is working fine with files like excel, word and PDF, but it's not working for text files means files we are opening with notepad, whether it is closed or not,
OS: windows 10

```
  import os

  file_location = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\abc.txt'
  file_dir = os.path.dirname(file_location)
  file_name = os.path.basename(file_location)
  relative_file_location = os.path.relpath(file_location)

  if os.path.exists(relative_file_location):
    os.chdir(file_dir)
    try: 
        os.rename(relative_file_location,file_name)
        print('File is closed')
    except OSError:
        print('File is still open.')
    else:
        print("Path does not exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the file is open. If it is then you can do anything with the file. If it happens to be closed it will give you an error if you try and open it. So I just except the error. Hopefully this helps.

```
try:
    myfile = open("myfile.csv", "r+") # or "a+", whatever you need
except IOError:
    print "Could not open file! Please close Excel!"

with myfile:
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: not working for text file or for files open with notepad